# What's the difference between Associate and other titles?

Tags: job-search, title

I'm looking at positions for myself, and as an analyst there's a large number of different positions with varying titles.

I can usually rule out data engineer and scientist, as well as database admin, but I get stuck when it comes to the difference between one analyst and another. I'm speaking more specifically about the difference between an associate data analyst and a data analyst, rather than business analyst versus financial analyst.

So far, I haven't been able to find anything that differentiates the two, but the job I applied for has "Associate" attached to the meaning. When looking up potential salaries in the case of an offer, I get a large range (>$10k) between data analyst and associate data analyst, and this confuses me.

**What is the difference between a data analyst and an associate data analyst?**

Comment: I guess this usage originates with [associate membership](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/associate-member) in a society or club.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically an associate prefix on a job title means that is a lower rank than a similar job title without the prefix. That is, an Associate Data Analyst would be a lower rank than just a Data Analyst.

But job titles are mostly meaningless. A company can call its jobs anything it wants. At the software company I work at now, an "Associate Software Engineer" is generally someone anywhere from entry-level to having 3 years experience. But compare that to my previous company that had no "Associate" level at all in its job title convention. An "associate software engineer" where I work now may actually have more experience and responsibility than a regular "software engineer" at my last company. They probably get paid more too.

It gets even more convoluted as you move up the ranks. I once talked to a marketing person who told me about their visits to other companies where everyone was a "VP of something-or-other". Very impressive titles. But when they asked those people what they actually did, they found out they had the same job as an "associate marketing manager" at their own company.

What you need to do when looking at job postings is look at what they are actually looking for in the position: how much experience, what responsibilities, what skills, etc. That's the only way to compare positions. The title is a loose indicator of the job (you don't need to bother looking at "senior" positions if you are entry-level), but doesn't really carry that much weight.